# How to create a dynamic array of React hooks for an array of components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

```js
const AnimatedText = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Text);

function Component({ texts }) {
  const [visitIndex, setVisitIndex] = React.useState(0);

  // can't create an array of shared value for each text
  // since useSharedValue is a hook, and that throws a warning
  const textScalesShared = texts.map((_) => useSharedValue(1));

  // can't create an array of animated style for each text
  // since useAnimatedStyle is a hook, and that throws a warning
  const animatedTextStyle = textScalesShared.map((shared) =>
    useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
      transform: [{ scale: shared.value }],
    }))
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    // code to reduce text scale one after another
    // it will loop over the array of textScaleShared values
    // passed to each component and update it
    if (visitIndex === texts.length) {
      return;
    }

    textScalesShared[visitIndex].value = withDelay(
      1000,
      withTiming(0.5, {
        duration: 1000,
      })
    );

    const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      setVisitIndex((idx) => idx + 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timerId);
    };
  }, [visitIndex]);

  return texts.map((text, index) => {
    if (index <= visitIndex) {
      return (
        <AnimatedRevealingText
          key={index}
          fontSize={fontSize}
          revealDuration={revealDuration}
          style={animatedStylesShared[index]}
          {...props}
        >
          {text}
        </AnimatedRevealingText>
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  });
}
```

I want to apply animated styles to an array of components, but since `useSharedValue` and `useAnimatedStyle` are both hooks, I am unable to loop over the prop and create a shared value and the corresponding style for each of the component.

How can I achieve the same?

EDIT: updated to add the full code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a component to handle the `useSharedValue` and `useAnimatedStyle`  hooks for every item using the `visitIndex` value:

**AnimatedTextItem.js**

```
const AnimatedText = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Text);

const AnimatedTextItem = ({text, visited}) => {
  const textScaleShared = useSharedValue(1);
  const style = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    transform: [{ textScaleShared.value }],
  }));

  useEffect(()=> {
    if(visited) {
      textScaleShared.value = withDelay(
        1000,
        withTiming(0.5, {
          duration: 1000,
        });
      );
    }
  }, [visited]);
  
  return (<AnimatedText style={style}>{text}</AnimatedText>)
}
```

**Component.js**

```
function Component({texts}) {
  const [visitIndex, setVisitIndex] = React.useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // code to reduce text scale one after another
    // it will loop over the array of textScaleShared values
    // passed to each component and update it
    if (visitIndex === texts.length) {
      return;
    }

    const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      setVisitIndex((idx) => idx + 1);
    }, revealDuration);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timerId);
    };
  }, []);
  return texts.map((text, index) => (<AnimatedTextItem text={text} visited={visitIndex === index}/>))
}
```

Comment: React can return only one component, and you must wrap the components array.

Comment: But this makes the `textScaleShared` variable to be inside the other component. In the code to reduce the text scale, I have a setInterval to loop over each textScaleShared value of each component and reduce them. How can I access the scale value now?

Comment: @TopW3 Yes, there is nothing wrong with that, see this working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zcdqfq

Comment: @mohsinulhaq there are missing part of your code, can you add those parts?

Comment: @mohsinulhaq I updated my answer, I can't test this code, but I think that you will get the idea of create a component to handle the style.

Answer (score 1):

You can compose a component to handle it for you, but you need to pass the index of the text you're mapping through.

Like this

```js
const AnimatedText = ({styleIndex}) => {
  const textScaleShared = useSharedValue(styleIndex + 1);

  const animatedTextStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    transform: [{ scale: textScaleShared.value }],
  }));
  
  const Animated = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Text);

  return <Animated style={animatedTextStyle}>{text}</Animated>;
};

function Component({ texts }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    // code to reduce text scale one after another
  }, []);

  return texts.map((text, index) => (
    <AnimatedText key={index} styleIndex={index}>
      {text}
    </AnimatedText>
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem :) Let me see if i can come up a solution.

You already notice `hook` can't be in a dynamic array since the length of array is unknown.

1. Multiple components
   You can have as many as components as you want, each one can have a hook, ex.

```
  const Text = ({ text }) => {
    // useSharedValue(1)
    // useAnimatedStyle
  }

  const Components = ({ texts }) => {
    return texts.map(text => <Text text={text} />)
  }
```

2. Single hook
   You can also see if you can find a className that can apply to all components at the same time. It's css i assume.